# Passed argument to the child process is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am running a script inside a script using `child_process.fork()`. I am using a variable (an instance of another application) inside my main script and I need to pass this as an argument to the subsequent script to get it updated there. I tried it following way

**Sub script**

```
console.log(process.data);
let a = process.data;
.....................
```

**Main script**

```
function runScript(scriptPath, data, callback) {

    var invoked = false;
    var process = childProcess.fork(scriptPath, data);

    process.on('error', function (err) {
        if (invoked) return;
        invoked = true;
        callback(err);
    });

    process.on('exit', function (code) {
        if (invoked) return;
        invoked = true;
        var err = code === 0 ? null : new Error('exit code ' + code);
        callback(err);
    });

} 

 let dataValues = "this from the main script";

 runScript('./subscript.js' ,dataValues, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('finished running some-script.js');
 });
```

I am getting `undefined` when I try to access the argument from the subsequent script. Seems like the argument is not sent to the subsequent script. It was running as expected if I don't pass arguments to the second script.

What is the issue with the way of my data sending to the subsequent script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fork(...)` expects a `string[]`, not a`string` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)), so try passing the arguments as an array:

```
let dataValues = ["this from the main script"];
```

Also, in the child process, you will receive the arguments in the [`process.argv` array](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv), not `process.data`. Try this for in child process script:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Can I send another data type than string to the child process? My actual argument is an instance of an application

Comment: You can't share object instances between processes, but you can convert objects to strings with `JSON.stringify` and convert them back to an object in your child process with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Actually, my argument is an instance of `.node` type variable, which is created wrapping c++ app. I make changes to that object in my main script and then I need to do further changes to the same instance in my subscript. Then I use those updated from subscript in my main script again. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can send args as command line arguments to your second script like

```
childProcess.fork(scriptPath+" "+data); //data can be a1 a2 a3
```

and then on your script (scriptPath) you can access them by process.argv

```
for (let j = 0; j < process.argv.length; j++) {  
    console.log(j + ' -> ' + (process.argv[j])); 
}
```

// output will be

```
0 -> a1
1 -> a2
2 -> a3
```

Comment: The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) suggest to use a string array instead of appending to the script path `scriptPath+" "+data`.